# calculateDistanceX(MotionEvent) method in intercept touch events handling

Tags: android, intercept

I'm new to android and trying to learn intercept touch events handling using [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#intercept), but i do not understand that `calculateDistanceX(MotionEvent)` method at all, and the more I searched about it the less i found. I'm completely confused.

Could anyone please explain it to me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what don't you understand?

Comment: Well, apparently, I didn't understand I should read the comments!
thanks anyway :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says that the method `calculateDistanceX()` is left as an exercise for a user. One solution would be to cache the first `MotionEvent` and then the distance would be `mFirstMotionEvent.getX() - currentMotionEvent.getX()`